# How do I filter a string on just numbers, dots and commas?

Tags: java, regex

Okay, so ive got a long string, and I want to remove everything thats inside, except for decimal numbers, comma's and dots,

I have tried:

```
str = str.replace("[^0-9\\.\\,]","");
```

But this just ends up in nothing..

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: You should put 2 or 3 examples of what you have in input, and what you want in output

Answer (score 23):

You don't need to escape the characters in the character group.  You should also be using `replaceAll()`.

```
str = str.replaceAll("[^0-9.,]+","");
```

Comment: It's easy to remember, because a dot as joker inside a group wouldn't make any sense. It couldn't mean more or less than a dot without a group. And Comma never needs masking in regexes.

Comment: And add a `+` for a little extra speed.

Comment: @jjnguy +1 this can be a shorter answer as well `str = str.replaceAll("\\D+","");`

Answer (score 5):

Try `str.replaceAll("[^0-9.,]+","");`